# RequestPermissionResult() method not calling

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions, request

In my application I am using Google map and thats why I am checking permissions for that as below :

```
if (!Constant.checkPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Constant.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 101);
        } else {
            if (Constant.isOnline(getActivity())) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                locationUpdate();
            } else {
                Constant.displayToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.msg_internet));
            }
        }
```

and I am handling result as below :

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FINE_LOCATION:
            Constant.displayToast(getActivity(),"FINE_LOCATION");
            Constant.displayLogE(">>>>","##"+"FINE_LOCATION");
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (!Constant.checkPermission(MapFragment.this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    Constant.requestPermission(MapFragment.this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, CORSE_LOCATION);
                    Constant.displayToast(getActivity(),"FINE_LOCATION calling inside");
                }
                Constant.displayLogE(">>>>","##"+"calling...");
                Constant.displayToast(getActivity(),"FINE_LOCATION calling");
               // locationUpdate();
            }
            break;
        case CORSE_LOCATION:
            Constant.displayLogE(">>>>","##"+"CORSE_LOCATION");
            Constant.displayToast(getActivity(),"calling here...");
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Constant.displayLogE(">>>>","##"+"calling here...");
                Constant.displayToast(getActivity(),"calling here...");
            }
            break;
        case 101:
            Constant.displayLogE(">>>>","##"+"CORSE_LOCATION");
            break;
    }
}
```

But, I can not found log for case 101 : that is ""##"+"CORSE_LOCATION"".
Stuck here..

What might be the issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you declare permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes sir, I have declared as  :  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: I just know `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(..)` rather than `Constant.checkPermission`

Comment: Sir, my this if condition is also not executing even my GPS is off..  if (!Constant.checkPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

Comment: Sir, Constant is my class, in which i have created method as below with ContextCompact : public static boolean checkPermission(Context mContext, String per) {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, per);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Answer (score -1):

Since you call a function that return a result from callback, you should write the callback function at your activity class instead of fragment, because your function is call by activity not fragment. So, just paste your callback function into your activity code. And remember if you override this function be sure call it's super function.